# Is it better to create a direct reference in Firebase Realtime Database than setting data directly at the parent?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user database as follows:

```
{
  users: {
    uid: {
      profile: {
        username: "Sherlock"
        dob: "01/01/1895"
      }
      profession: {
        name: "Consulting Detective"
        type: "Business"
      }
   }
}
```

In my code, I have the whole object user with the same properties.

Say if I had to change the profession type, would it better to go to the exact path -

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(uid).child("preferences").set(type);
```

Or would it be better to post the whole object directly at the reference?

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").set(user);
```

I wish to optimize for performance and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a write operation, the Firebase client will send the entire data you pass to `set()` to the server. So it's typically best to only send the minimal data to the server, to minimize bandwidth.

However, do consider if you have any internal dependencies between the data in `user`. If there are dependencies, you might want to send the entire object, as that allows the server to accept/reject the entire operation, and prevent the data getting inconsistent.

Essentially: think of what needs to happen when two client are writing different properties of the user at the same time. If that should be possible, use writes at the lowest level possible. If only one client should be able to modify a user at each time, writing the entire user object is the easiest way to accomplish that.